# Kibana receives "Connection refused" on the browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am receiving the following error when attempting to connect to Kibana through my browser:

`The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.`
```

My current kibana configuration is as follows:

I have the IP address set to the Elastic IP address of my AWS server. I have Elastic hosts set to my three Elasticsearch nodes. The username and passwords are filled in. I have set it to be reachable on port 5601.

As for my server, it is an AWS server that is located within my primary VPC. It has a security group set so that my local IP address (only my local IP) can connect to port 5601 directly. Beyond that SSH is open within the VPC.

Any ideas what I have wrong in my configuration? Obviously, for security reasons no IP addresses will be posted here. Thank you!

Editing to note that I can curl to it from the server itself (as long as I use the IP and not localhost).

Comment: Can you share your kibana config? it's not visible. Please test `curl -ks "elasticsearch_url:es_port" -u elastic:password` *from where kibana installed*. And last but not least stop kibana service and run on terminal and share the result. `./bin/kibana --allow-root`.

Comment: commenting to mention that the solution was to make the IP for kibana be 0.0.0.0